# Button Error When Clicked

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

i have a problem when i press the button

i really appreciate if someone can help me

```
public class submit implements Button.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        no = " "+noper.getText();
        na = " "+nama.getText();

        if (rb1.isChecked())
            j = " Male ";
        if (rb2.isChecked())
            j = " Female ";

        ag = (String) agamalist.getSelectedItem();  

        tl = (String) Spinner01.getSelectedItem() + "-"
                + (String) Spinner02.getSelectedItem() + "-"
                + (String) Spinner03.getSelectedItem();

        ju = "";
        if (c1.isChecked())
            ju += " TK ";
        if (c2.isChecked())
            ju += " SI ";
        if (c3.isChecked())
            ju += " TE ";

        t1.setText(no);
        t2.setText(na);
        t3.setText(j);
        t4.setText(ag);
        t5.setText(tl);
        t6.setText(ju);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    }
}
```

the program start correctly but when i press the button , its just unfortunately and close my program.

here is the log cat

```
11-11 06:52:18.298: I/Choreographer(1879): Skipped 166 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-11 06:52:18.328: D/gralloc_goldfish(1879): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-11 06:52:19.138: I/Choreographer(1879): Skipped 161 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-11 06:52:23.799: I/Choreographer(1879): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-11 06:52:25.649: D/AndroidRuntime(1879): Shutting down VM
11-11 06:52:25.649: W/dalvikvm(1879): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
11-11 06:52:25.739: E/AndroidRuntime(1879): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 06:52:25.739: E/AndroidRuntime(1879): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 06:52:25.739: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at com.IrvanKosini.kuis1.MainActivity$submit.onClick(MainActivity.java:100)
11-11 06:52:25.739: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
11-11 06:52:25.739: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
11-11 06:52:25.739: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-11 06:52:25.739: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-11 06:52:25.739: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 06:52:25.739: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-11 06:52:25.739: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 06:52:25.739: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-11 06:52:25.739: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-11 06:52:25.739: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 06:52:27.999: I/Process(1879): Sending signal. PID: 1879 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: issue can be anywhere. Post the logcat

Comment: use no = " "+noper.getText().toString; and same for "na"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG... why are you creating a whole class..?

you can do this in a short and sweet method too.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          // do your work here
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class should implements the View.OnClickListener, implement the abstract method OnClick to do whatever you want. In onCreate() method also set the listener to the button:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```